# What does -E mean in sudo apt-get

Tags: linux, proxy, apt-get

I have a linux-mint VM that is sitting behind a proxy.  I have been trying to install vsftpd using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

This gave me the error

```
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80
```

So then I remembered somebody had once told me to use the -E flag

```
sudo -E apt-get install vsftpd
```

And this worked! Can anyone please explain what this flag means and why it should be used when you are behind a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-E preserves environment variables. 
Your proxy connection settings are stored in the env of the current user.
If you elevate to root via sudo, those connection settings do not appear anymore to apt-get. With the option, the env variable is kept the same for both your user and root, so apt-get can see your proxy settings.

You can compare what is defined using the following commands :

```
$env
$sudo env
$sudo -E env
```

Answer (score 1):

The -E option (or --preserve-env)
Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

From this documentation https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html

vsftpd may set a environment variable on installation